# How to return diferent pages in React functional component

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, react-hooks, react-functional-component

Im creating a react app and when my app starts i want to know if the user is logged in to send him to home page.
When my app starts "/" route load this page

```
import React from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { LocalStorageService } from "../services/localData-service";


const HomeOrLogin : React.FC = () => {
    /*If User is logged then, redirect to home, if not redirect to slides tutorial*/ 
    const storageService = new LocalStorageService();
    // Check if exits jwt in the phone
    storageService.getItem("jwt")
        .then((token )=>{
            /* If exists the jwt in the phone the user is logged */ 
            if(token){
                return <Redirect to="/Home" /> 
            }else{
                return <Redirect to="/slides" />
            }               
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
                console.log(err);
        })
};

export default HomeOrLogin;
```

But it show me an error in component

```
Type '() => void' is not assignable to type 'FC<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, any> | null'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered doing your async petition in the componentDidMount and then in return one or another screen?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const HomeOrLogin : React.FC = () => {
    const [ redirect, setRedirect ] = useState(null);
    /*If User is logged then, redirect to home, if not redirect to slides tutorial*/ 

    useEffect(() => {
        const storageService = new LocalStorageService();
            // Check if exits jwt in the phone
            storageService.getItem("jwt")
                .then((token )=>{
                /* If exists the jwt in the phone the user is logged */ 
                    if(token){
                        setRedirect('/Home');
                    }              
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.log(err);
                })
    }, []);

    if (redirect) 
        return <Redirect to={redirect} />
    }
    return (
        <Redirect to="/slides" />
    )

 };
```

That way if there is a token you would be redirected to Home and else just redirected to /slides.

Comment: Hi, im new in react, ```Cannot find name 'componentDidMount'.``` Maybe is couse im building with ionic react ?

Comment: Sorry bro, you are using a functinal component, I'll edit it

Comment: No problem mate!